# How can I Prevent Blinking Issue in Real-Time Notification Dialog Box Triggered by Socket.io Events?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I am working on a JavaScript application that uses socket.io for real-time updates. I have a function that is triggered by a socket event ("to_client_a"), and it checks the distance between two markers. If the distance is less than or equal to 30, a notification dialog box is displayed.

```
socket.on("to_client_a", function (data) {
  console.log(`Received from B: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);

  var dt = JSON.stringify(data);
  var newLatLng = new L.LatLng(data.Y, data.X);

  var marker1LatLng = marker1.getLatLng();
  var marker2LatLng = marker2.getLatLng();

  var distance = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(marker2LatLng.lat - marker1LatLng.lat, 2) +
      Math.pow(marker2LatLng.lng - marker1LatLng.lng, 2)
  );

  let dialogbox = document.getElementById("dialog-box");
  let timerBar = document.getElementById("timer-bar");

  console.log("Distance:", distance);
  if (distance <= 30) {
    mymap.removeLayer(marker1);
    dialogbox.classList.remove("display-box");
    dialogbox.classList.add("display-box");

    setTimeout(function () {
      dialogbox.classList.remove("display-box");
      dialogbox.classList.add("hidden-box");
      timerBar.style.width = "0";
    }, 4000);
    timerBar.classList.add("animate");
  }
  console.log("Received marker2 data:", dt);
});
```

The issue I'm facing is that when the socket receives new coordinates, the condition for displaying the dialog box is true, causing the dialog box to blink. It seems like the condition is being continuously evaluated with the new values.

I've tried to debug the issue, but I'm not sure how to prevent the dialog box from blinking. Any suggestions on how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, I expected that when the socket receives new coordinates, the condition (distance <= 30) would be evaluated once, and if true, the dialog box would be displayed without causing any blinking. Instead, it appears that the condition is continuously re-evaluating with the new values, resulting in the blinking behavior.